# Remove legend bar in R using Image.Plot

Tags: field, heatmap

This is the test code im using

```
x_coord <- c(1,2,3,4)
y_coord <- c(1,2,3,4)
value <- c(12,15,19,30)
foo <- data.frame(x_coord, y_coord, value)
library(MBA)
foo=foo[ order(foo[,1], foo[,2],foo[,3]), ]
mba.int <- mba.surf(foo, 300, 300, extend=T)$xyz.est
library(fields)
fields::image.plot(mba.int,legend.only = FALSE, axes=FALSE)
```

The axes part deletes the axis, but when i try to remove the legend bar, the vertical bar indicating the color measurements, it will not go away.

i have tried smallplot = 1, but that gives me an error but it gets rid of the vertical legend,

Anyone have any idea of how to get rid of the legend without any errors produced ?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the color legend, just use the built-in [image](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/image.html) function instead. The function you are using is designed specifically for adding a legend easily.

If you want to keep the same color scheme as the fields `image.plot` function:

```
image(<your data>, ..., col = tim.colors())
```

Using this creates the exact same image without a legend.

Answer (score 0):

The `image` and `image.plot` functions actually have quite different plotting functionality.
One problem (at least for me, trying to plot regional climate model data) with using the built-in `image` is that it cannot handle irregular grids. The `image.plot` function uses the `poly.image` function internally to create the plot. Both are included in the `fields` package. The good thing is that the `poly.image` function also can be used on its own, for example like this:

```
library("fields")
# create an example of an irregular 3x3 grid by adding random perturbations up to ±0.6
x <- matrix(rep(1:3,each=3) + 0.6*runif(9), ncol=3)
y <- matrix(rep(7:9,times=3) + 0.6*runif(9), ncol=3)
# 9 values, from 1 to 9
z <- matrix(1:9,nrow=3)

# Please avoid the default rainbow colours, see e.g.
# https://www.climate-lab-book.ac.uk/2014/end-of-the-rainbow/
# Other examples of colour schemes: https://colorbrewer2.org/
col <- colorRampPalette(c("#2c7bb6","#abd9e9","#ffffbf","#fdae61","#d7191c"))(9)

par(mfrow=c(1,3), mar=c(4,4,4,1), oma=c(0,0,0,0))
image(x=7:9,y=1:3,z,col=col, main="image()\n Only regular grid. Also note transposition.")
image.plot(x,y,z,col=col, main="image.plot()\n Always with colorbar.")
poly.image(x,y,z,col=col, main="poly.image()\n Does not include colorbar.")
```

[image: Figure showing comparison of results from image, image.plot and poly.image functions]